# Finding the axis of an O

Tags: typography

Having looked at some illustrations that are supposed to explain the
concept of an axis, I'm confused.  Is finding the axis of an `O` merely
a matter of drawing a line through its thinnest parts, or is there more
to it?

Comment: That really depends on the typeface you are looking at. Could you explain a bit more what kind of typefaces you are referring to, preferably with an image? We tend to be rather visually-oriented here, I have no clue why ;)

Comment: Welcome on GD.SE, Toothrot. Please refine your question, and try also to add a sample image. The shape of an "O" in different typefaces could be circular, elliptic, asymmetric...Sometimes you cannot have an axis at all. Findnig the axis for a circle is very simple, for an ellipse see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53093/how-to-find-the-center-of-an-ellipse).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, no more complicated than this!

> An imaginary line drawn from top to bottom of a glyph bisecting the
>   upper and lower strokes is the axis.
>   Source: https://typedecon.com/blogs/type-glossary/axis/

**It's one thing to draw the axis of an existing font vs. designing a font with a coherent distribution of thicks and thins throughout.**

If you've ever tried using a flat calligraphy nib, you'll have noticed that thicks and thins are distributed differently depending on the angle at which you are holding the pen.

Typically, the axis on the O will help **identify different type families** in the [Vox-AtypI classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vox-ATypI_classification)...
As explained in  http://www.typographher.com/glossary :

> A completely vertical axis results in a neutral, upright posture. When
>   the axis leans left or right the letterforms have (positive or
>   negative) stress. Often in old-style typefaces the axis is more
>   inclined, and in transitional and didone faces, it’s vertical.
>   Rational and geometric typefaces often have a neutral axis (and
>   stress).